# Zooming the images in thumbnail preview column in Asset library display form

Tags: library, image

We have an asset library. on serach results we have customised the XSLT to show the thumbnail and used Highslide jQuery to zoom the thumbnail on click of the image.
we want the same functionality to implement in the display form of asset library.
By default, thumbnail preview column in display form opens the image in same window and we want to override that.